# Applying forces on an object

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

If i've understood right, when i "applyForce" it is pushing my object in my vector direction and power for as long as the applyForce is applied.
but when i try to apply force on a body in 'touchesBegan' (because i want it to pushed up as long as i touch the screen) all i get is a little push that makes it jump for few pixels and then it falls down as a result of the physicsWorld settings.
(I also want the force stop pushing when 'touchesEnded')
ideas anybody?
Thanks

(Xcode 5, spriteKit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

touchesBegan: will only fire once when the screen is touched.

To continue to do something for as long as your finger is touching the screen you can do something like this:

Create a BOOL ivar

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    BOOL theFingerTouches;
}
```

Next register the touch as you already know how

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    theFingerTouches = true;
}
```

Make sure to also register when the touch is no longer present

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    theFingerTouches = false;
}
```

Lastly use the update: method to do what you need depending on your BOOL

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if(theFingerTouches == true)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```